# Could not upload images from admin panel after updating Magento to 1.9.3

Tags: magento

I am trying to upload image from admin panel but could not upload images only in product tab. But I can upload image for category tab perfectly. My error message is:

[image]

I have also checked `/public_html/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php`, line 219:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
```

and line 541:

```
if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true)))
```

both looks OK.

Also checked permission of `/public_html/media/catalog/product` folder and it is also set as 777.

Comment: Can you read log file?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw yes, but nothing in it related to this upload issue

Comment: What is your image dimensions?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw I tried to upload only 297X298 size image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After **SUPEE-8788** update, magento introduce image dimensions in the configuration. I'm not sure your previous version is what. The error came from `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`.

So, my recommendation is Go and Check your dimensions setting under

**System->Configuration->Catalog->Product Image**.

[image]

Hope this help. Btw, default dimensions size is **5000px**

Comment: No it is not solving my issue.I tried to upload only 297X298 size of png image but still this error comes and also deleted all ty[pe of cache and index and then log out and logged in again, but nothing works!!

Comment: Yes, I tried it again and checked my setting again.

Comment: @GauravJariwala Can you check this out this article. http://thewebsiteguy.xyz/magento-cant-upload-images-ce-1-9-2-3-supee-7405-update/ But,